# How to use For-loop in xquery?

Tags: for-loop, xquery

I'm having an url-pattern like `"http://www.asdf.com/pages=1"`, now I want to operate for loop for this url-pattern upto 1547 i.e., (`"http://www.asdf.com/pages=1547"`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might do what you need:

```
for $i in (1 to 10, 1547, 1548)
return concat("http://www.asdf.com/pages=", $i)
```

Comment: Thanks and more query., if the url pattern is like this "http://www.asdf.com.?sid=1545148454855&page=1?sid=ABGDBSDGH58569ASDE" , now i have to change this thing?

Comment: What about `return concat("asdf.com.?sid=1545148454855&page=", $i, "?sid=ABGDBSDGH58569ASDE&q…")`?

Comment: One more query adn how to replace "?" with "" [Null] in xquery.

Comment: You'll have to escape the ampersand characters `&` as `&amp;` too, so it should be more like `concat(http://www.asdf.com./?sid=1545148454855&amp;page=', $i, '?sid=ABGDBSDGH58569ASDE&amp;q...')`.

Comment: for replacing substrings, please look at [`fn:replace($string, $pattern, $replacement)`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/#func-replace).

Comment: Yeah! i got that, but i'm unable to replace "?" with null.

Answer (score 3):

```
for $i in (1 to 1547)
return concat("http://www.asdf.com/pages=",$i)
```